# swift - centre a number of views vertically without dummy spacer views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Say I have 2 views (labels or textfields) with varying heights positioned above each other (not on top).  I would like the group centred vertically in the superview.

I know I could use a dummy spacer view above and below and set equal height in storyboard.  I'm no expert, but this doesn't seem right to me.

Can it be done in storyboard by setting the top constraint for the top view equal to the bottom constraint of the bottom view?

Comment: i have found the best way to do this see it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bP6hgg6cYAY and http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/setting-up-equal-vertical-spacing-for-components-using-autolayout/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your subviews' heights will change at runtime (either because you change the number of lines of text in them, or because you support [Dynamic Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW65) like a good iOS app should), then **no**, you cannot do this with just constraints. You either need an extra view or you need to change the constraint constants from code. If you go with an extra view (which I recommend), you can do it with a single extra view.

The simplest solution, if your deployment target is iOS 9 or later, is to put your subviews into a vertical `UIStackView` and center the `UIStackView` in the superview. You might not need any constraints directly on the subviews depending on the layout you want.

If you can't use a stack view, you can use a spacer view. First, set up vertical spacing constraints between your subviews to glue them together with whatever padding you want. Then add a spacer view next to the subviews. Set the spacer view to hidden. (Hidden views still participate in layout.) Constrain the spacer's top edge to your top subview's top edge, and constrain the spacer's bottom edge to your bottom subview's bottom edge. Then constrain the spacer to be vertically centered in its container (which should be the superview).

You also need to add horizontal constraints on the spacer to keep Xcode from complaining, but the horizontal size and position don't really matter since the spacer is hidden. So just put it somewhere convenient.

Here's the final set of constraints and layout:

[image: constraints and layout]

The spacer is the skinny pink view.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it easily via `center vertically`, control and drag the object you want to centre in Storyboard, choose `center vertically in container`. This way you can centre these subviews in superView individually. If you want to centre these subviews together, you can create another `containerView` to contain these views(labels, textFields), then centre the `containerView` in superView.

Hope this help:-)

### Control and drag in Storyboard

[image]

### Center three subView individually.

[image]

### Center them together with a container view

[image]

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clearer.  But the views are above each other.  I've edited the question to make it clearer.